# c - function pointer - why pass a struct as an argument?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm reading the source code below for a program and trying to understand function pointers. Taking `lwm2m_read_callback_t` as an example, this is a function pointer correct? Is there an obvious reason why the 4th argument takes a pointer to the `lwm2m_object_t` struct itself?

```
/*
 * LWM2M Objects
 *
 * For the read callback, if *numDataP is not zero, *dataArrayP is pre-allocated
 * and contains the list of resources to read.
 *
 */

typedef struct _lwm2m_object_t lwm2m_object_t;

typedef uint8_t (*lwm2m_read_callback_t) (uint16_t instanceId, int * numDataP, lwm2m_data_t ** dataArrayP, lwm2m_object_t * objectP);
typedef uint8_t (*lwm2m_discover_callback_t) (uint16_t instanceId, int * numDataP, lwm2m_data_t ** dataArrayP, lwm2m_object_t * objectP);
typedef uint8_t (*lwm2m_write_callback_t) (uint16_t instanceId, int numData, lwm2m_data_t * dataArray, lwm2m_object_t * objectP);
typedef uint8_t (*lwm2m_execute_callback_t) (uint16_t instanceId, uint16_t resourceId, uint8_t * buffer, int length, lwm2m_object_t * objectP);
typedef uint8_t (*lwm2m_create_callback_t) (uint16_t instanceId, int numData, lwm2m_data_t * dataArray, lwm2m_object_t * objectP);
typedef uint8_t (*lwm2m_delete_callback_t) (uint16_t instanceId, lwm2m_object_t * objectP);

struct _lwm2m_object_t
{
    struct _lwm2m_object_t * next;           // for internal use only.
    uint16_t       objID;
    lwm2m_list_t * instanceList;
    lwm2m_read_callback_t     readFunc;
    lwm2m_write_callback_t    writeFunc;
    lwm2m_execute_callback_t  executeFunc;
    lwm2m_create_callback_t   createFunc;
    lwm2m_delete_callback_t   deleteFunc;
    lwm2m_discover_callback_t discoverFunc;
    void * userData;
};


typedef struct _lwm2m_list_t
{
    struct _lwm2m_list_t * next;
    uint16_t    id;
} lwm2m_list_t;
```

Comment: Presumably because the function will modify the members of the structure addressed by the passed parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It is a way to modify the struct in a different function from the function where the struct is initialized.  This way you can modify the struct by reference.
In C you can only return one variable and passing variables by reference is a way to still be able to modify multiple variables in a function.

Say you want to modify 2 integers in a function:

```
void myfunc(int *a, int *b) {
    *a = *b + 3;
    *b = *a;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int b =  5;
    myfunc(&a, &b);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this allows you to change the variables my reference.

The same can be done with structures.

Answer (score 0):

All those typedef functions are saying that, the fourth parameter is a struct pointer type "lwm2m_object_t".

Obviously you will be passing the respective struct object as parameter, when you invoke those functions.